# C++ copying char* using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I am trying to grasp pointers and I have this simple code for which I need some explanation.

I need to copy one char array to another. In my main function I have this code:

```
const int MAX_SIZE = 100;

char x[MAX_SIZE] = "1234565";
char* y = new char[MAX_SIZE];

copyArray(x, y);    
std::cout << y;

delete [] y;
```

Now comes the question, how does this code (which works jut fine):

```
while ((*dest = *source) != '\0')
{
    dest += 1;
    source += 1;
}
```

Differ from this (gives strange characters at the end):

```
while (*source != '\0')
{
    *dest = *source;

    dest += 1;
    source += 1;
}
```

Looking at this it seems those two functions are pretty similar.
It makes sense that we are copying until we reach a null-terminator in the source string, right (2nd function)?

But it's not working correctly - I get some strange characters at the end of the copied array. However, the first function works just fine.

```
void copyArray(const char* source, char* dest);
```

Comment: Right, I did the suggested tag twice, sorry

Comment: `while ((*dest = *source) != '\0')` guarantees that the necessary terminating `'\0'` character will be copied before the loop ends. Also see http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: You mean in the second example it will break the loop when it encounters '\0' meaning that it won't terminate the string?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that.

Comment: @daavid245 Detail:  The `while (*source != '\0')` loop does not "won't terminate the string".  It won't terminate  the character array.  A character array is not a string until it has a null character.

Comment: @user0042 Are you sure that’s the issue with this test code in particular? The `new` statement should zero-initialize the allocated data so that shouldn’t have an effect in this case.

Comment: @Daniel Do you have a standard reference guaranteeing the zero initialization? I'm not sure about that. Something like `char* y = new char[MAX_SIZE]{0};` maybe.

Comment: @user0042 I think I was wrong about that. I had just reading a source I thought was trustworthy which said it was, but that goes against both my previous thought and what I’m seeing now. Maybe I just misread the thing saying it was zero-initialized.

Answer (score 1):

`(*dest = *source)` is an evaluated expression just like the 1+1 part of `int i = 1+1;` so, after it is evaluated, the value is usable in an other expression

The difference is that in `((*dest = *source) != '\0')`, the value of *source is assigned to *dest, then the whole expression is evaluated ( expression has the same value than `*source` )  while the value pointed by `*source` is only used to evaluate `*source != '\0'`, but never assigned during the evaluation of that statement.

---

EDIT

user0042 brings a realy acute observation : by doing so, the following code

```
while ((*dest = *source) != '\0')
{
    dest += 1;
    source += 1;
}
```

ensures that the final char of the array has a value of '\0'

Answer (score 1):

The form

```
while ((*dest = *source) != '\0')
{
    dest += 1;
    source += 1;
}
```

guarantees that the assignment of the character to copy (`(*dest = *source)`) is applied before testing the condition if the terminating `'\0'` character is reached is evaluated to `false`.

The second version doesn't copy the terminating `'\0'` character, because the loop ends before the

```
*dest = *source;
```

statement is ever reached.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you incrementing the addresses of `x, y` thus until the last character they point to Null-terminator so you have to declare a temporary variables to hold the first address:

```
char* x = "1234565";
char* y = new char[MAX_SIZE];

// Temporary pointers to hold the first element's address
char* tmp1 = x;
char* tmp2 = y;

while( (*y = *x) != '\0'){
    x += 1; // X no longer points to the first element
    y += 1; // Y no longer points to the first element
}

std::cout << tmp2;
```

- You can use a `do while` loop instead of `while`:

  ```
  char* x = "1234565";
  const int size = strlen(x);
  char* y = new char[size];

  char* tmp1 = x;
  char* tmp2 = y;

  do{
      *y = *x;
      x += 1;
      y += 1;
  }while( *(x - 1) != '\0');

  // Now no need for adding a null-terminator it is already added in the loop
  //  tmp2[size] = '\0';

  std::cout << tmp2;
  ```

Because Assigning the values before incrementing so the last character `\0` will break the loop before added to the destination pointer `y`. Thus I made the loop breaks not on `n = '\0'` but on `n - 1 = '\0'` to ensure that it is added to `y`.

Comment: he increments `x` and `y` in both examples